# Laravel 5 Unexpected response code 500 for android devices

Tags: php, android, laravel-5

i'm new in laravel 5, in laravel 4 i have this simple route:

```
Route::any('/register_by_mobile', function()
{
    echo json_encode(['result' => '123']);
});
```

and i get simply result in android device without any problem, but after use this route in laravel 5 i get error:

```
Unexpected response code 500 for http://192.168.1.6/asrebidaree/register_by_mobile
```

whats problem in laravel 5 and how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Check your server logs, your server has an internal error.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your URL is wrong? Can you try this:

```
Route::any('asrebidaree/register_by_mobile', function()
{
  echo json_encode(['result' => '123']);
});
```